# export PDF annotations (PDF-Tools)

Tags: pdf-tools

I started to use PDF-Tools for highlighting and annotations PDFs.
My question is how to extract/export these annotations and highlights to a document (org buffer for instance) from a PDF. I couldn't find a way to do this within PDF-tools.